# Mysql repeated results with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by, group-concat

I have this query :

```
SELECT `bot_content`.*, COUNT(bot_content_file.contentId) AS `files`, GROUP_CONCAT(category.title) AS `category_title` FROM `bot_content`
LEFT JOIN `bot_content_file` ON `bot_content`.`id`=`bot_content_file`.`contentId`
LEFT JOIN `category_item` ON `bot_content`.`id`=`category_item`.`entityId`
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id`=`category_item`.`categoryId`
WHERE `bot_content`.`botId` = '2'
GROUP BY `bot_content`.`id`
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

`bot_content` has **"1 to many"** relation with `bot_content_file` and `category_item`
`category` has **"1 to many"** relation with `category_item`

I ma trying to select all the contents and "number of files in each content" and a list of "category items" for each content.
The result returns repeated "category titles" for the number of the files.
If I remove the joins to `bot_content_file` table it works currently.

[image]

so what should I group by with to fix this? or should I use a nested select instead?

Comment: If a given `bot_content` will only ever reference a single category, you can abuse MySQL's slack grouping (if not in strict mode) and simply `select category.title` without `group_concat()`.  Otherwise, if you want a *particular* category of those referenced, which would you like: perhaps something like `max()` instead of `group_concat()`?  Or if you'd like a list of all the different ones, you can add the `distinct` keyword: `select group_concat(distinct category.title)`.

Comment: @eggyal each content can have many categories. `DISTINCT` works, tnx